# How to redirect external links on a specific page to a redirect page (wordpress)?

Tags: hyperlink, external

- I want to redirect visitors that click on my external links to a page like (you are leaving our site after x seconds ) then they redirect to the external links.
- I want to put ads on this page to increase my page view and earn extra money can anyone help me out.

***I can't code. If anyone helps with any code or script to solve the mentioned problem, then it tells where to place any code. Thanks***

Answer (score 0):

Previously I also asked the same thing about this, from many forums on the internet no one gave a good answer.

**Redirect external links** on a specific page to a redirect page (wordpress) often also referred to as *safelink*.

The idea is to create an outbound page for all external links to make the web **more structured and increase pageviews**.

Indirectly, this can also increase revenue from visible ad impressions because there are more page views.

There a tutorials to create this features **without using plugin**, pure coding and modify theme.

Here the answer, it is Indonesian language you can translate to english : [Safelink Wordpress](https://jagad.id/tutorial-cara-membuat-safelink-wordpress-self-hosted-gratis-sendiri-terbaru/)

This is need a lot step, you need modification on theme and create javascript.

Generally this method is widely used on wordpress download sites, you can see a example at: [Demo Web](https://adammuiz.com/download-office-2021/)

I hope this is solution that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You will get everything you are looking for in the [WP Safelink Plugin](https://previewon.com/wp-safelink-review-maximize-your-google-adsense-revenue-in-wordpress/) (Wordpress).
It will redirect all external links on a specific page.

1. Visitors will face Captcha verification.
2. The visitor will be redirected to a random wordpress post's content. After x seconds, a clickable download link or button will appear. When visitors click on the button, he/she will be redirected to the external link.

Of course, this method has been widely used by other bloggers. Even you don't need to know to code for this. This plugin will do it for you. So do you want to miss this method and ignore the results of Adsense?

You can see an example at Previewon.com.
There are many features available in safelink plugn like Adlinkfly integration, Anti Adblock, and so on.

I hope this is the solution that you're looking for.